# Cypress E2E Tests for eCommerce: How to test payment sandbox e.g. Amazon? Multi domain testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, automated-tests, cross-domain, e-commerce, cypress

i want to test by means of **Cypress** an E2E scenario for the checkout process in the web shop. Payment with Amazon pay and paypal is a part of this scenario. So when you click the button 'Amazon pay' it redirects to the other domain e.g. **[www.amazon.de/ap/signin](http://www.amazon.de/ap/signin)** and then after I log in successfully it redirects me back to the checkout page where I can continue my purchase process. So test example:

```
it('Test 1', () => {     
   cy.visit(first_url, { timeout: 90000 })
   cy.get('button').contains('Cookies').click() 
   cy.contains('Cart').click() 
   cy.contains('Buy Now').click()
   cy.get('#amazon-pay').click()   // here it redirects to amazon pay sandbox and cypress stops
```

})

I know that **cypress** not good with *iframes* and *cross domain* tests.
So my question: Have anybody tried to mock somehow payment part or to use API-test inside the cypress tes to make payment without using this sandbox page(or heard about). I have tried to test payment domain in the separate cypress test but not successfully - after cypress clicks "Amazon Pay" button and redirects to amazon sandbox page, cypress stops. I just want to check all methods before I switch into selenium. Thank you.

Comment: Does it help adding `"chromeWebSecurity": false,` in cypress.json? More [details](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Same-superdomain-per-test)